# Cannot set active sheet on open

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets (tabs).  I added the below code in an attempt to show the "Dashboard" tab every time someone opens the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
End Sub
```

When I open the spreadsheet I am presented with the `PROTECTED VIEW` banner.  I click "Enable Editing" and then I get the following error:

[image: Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set]

I also tried another option based on the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003.aspx):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
End Sub
```

This resulted in another error:

[image: Run-time error 1004: Activate method of Worksheet class failed]

Comment: Would the workbook happen to be saved with multiple sheets selected?

Comment: Since the Error 91 is complaining about a variable not set, and you're code contains no variables, then the error is probably coming from other code.  Have you tried this with other spreadsheets or just this specific one containing "Dashboard"?  I just created a new XLSX, added a sheet named "Dashboard" and added your code (from the first blurb) and it worked as expected (changed to the Dashboard sheet on Open, without error).  Add a breakpoint to you line there and then when it stops there continue by stepping through all the code until you figure out what's throwing the error.

Comment: I checked every other sheet for code and did find some.  However after deleting it I still have the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, [this known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2745652) affects Excel 2013 Office 365 edition and is the cause of my troubles.

The fix is to move `Activate` to the `Workbook_Activate()` event instead of `Workbook_Open()`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  Sheet1.Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Everything works fine now.

Comment: Just found a huge problem with this... if the spreadsheet loses focus and then you switch back to it it will process the `workbook_Activate()` method again :(

Comment: You could use a cell and set a value to it after the `activate`... and as long as it remains, the action will not be triggered... while erasing it `beforesave`... if you get what I mean...

Comment: That's a great idea.  Wouldn't it be cleaner to set some sort of global variable in the VBA?  Can you even do that?

Comment: Theoretical it would.. but `stop` vba and it will be reset again...

Comment: Maybe just set the variable on deactivating... would be the easiest way... also for the rare chance of resetting vba... would be acceptable to switch once to my eye...

Comment: You can't do that for 2 days now :(

Comment: Oh... second time I learned something new here :D

Answer (score 3):

That comes mainly cus the workbook is not "ready" to execute. But you can use a trick here:

In Module:

```
Public Sub InitActive()
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
End Sub
```

And Change your initial macro to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnTime Now, "InitActive"
End Sub
```

Application.OnTime silently waits till excel tells it to be "ready"... this way no errors should pop up... Still you should use the code name like `Sheet3.Activate` (if you know what I mean)

Comment: I was *super* excited, but sadly: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'OnTime' of object '_Application' failed`

Comment: WHAT?... thats confusing... which version of excel do you use? And Windows? Have you tried to recreate the error with a new workbook? (rarely a workbook itself contains an error)

Comment: Well this is weird.  I tried recreating the issue in a new workbook and I get this: `Cannot run the macro "C:\<path>\test.xlsm'!InitActive'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.`  Here is a screenshot of my code: http://imgur.com/7kHXa0Y

Comment: Also, Windows 8.1 x64 with Excel 2013 (Office 365 edition)

Comment: Excel is set to "Disable all macros with notification".  I had no notification on this blank workbook.

Comment: On both spreadsheets I can manually run the `InitActive` macro and it works as expected.

Comment: does the direct calling of `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Activate` work in the new book? (without using the OnTime)

Comment: Yes, see this MSDN article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2745652  I posted an answer

Comment: i saw it... makes my answer obsolete for this case... :P

Comment: It was still a good idea :)